# VB.net Open OneNote with command line switches

Tags: vb.net, process.start, onenote

anyone know best way to open OneNote with supporting command line switches?

For example:

```
Process.Start("OneNote.exe", "/nologo")
```

This just opens OneNote and still shows the splash screen. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it now is correct to say. One thing to mention though is the version of `OneNote` you are using, I believe that only works for 2007 and nothing newer.

You have a few option's to start `OneNote` with line switches. You can either use the `Process.Start` or `ProcessStartInfo` to accomplish this. Please see example's below.

1. **This is straight to the point and will work** (*depending on the version of OneNote*)

   ```
   Process.Start("OneNote.exe", "/nologo")
   ```
2. **Another option to use is ProcessStartInfo** (*same concept as above, but broken out)*. I used `/paste` to confirm this and it pasted what I had in the ClipBoard to OneNote

   ```
   'Create the new StartInfo
   Dim prsi As New ProcessStartInfo("OneNote.exe")
   prsi.Arguments = "/paste"

   'Start the actual process
   Process.Start(prsi)
   ```

**To view more command line switches** you can look **https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Command-line-switches-in-Microsoft-Office-OneNote-2007-29468957-1fcc-48b8-8821-00fe5518493a** there.

Comment: According to MS, the switches work up to OneNote version 2013. But I have tried both and they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make it with `Dim proc as new system.diagnostics.process`

And then use `proc.startinfo.arguments = "/nologo"`

Comment: For what ever reason, OneNote continues to show the logo no matter what I do.

Here is my current code:
`Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("OneNote.exe")
                    startInfo.Arguments = "/nologo"
                    Process.Start(startInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use quotes around the switch.
Use quotes ***only*** around the executable.

Like this:

```
Process.Start("OneNote.exe", /nologo)
```

Now, let me add here that a soap dish probably has more knowledge about VB.net than me.  So as far as the rest of the call (comma, spacing, etc), I'll trust you've got that nailed.  ;)